# setting font-size in jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am developing an app with jquery-mobile. (yes, and app, it'll run within cordova(aka phone gap))

On the nexus 7 (the target device for the app), The font displays for many things are way too small. I can barely read it and I'm young. Many of the users of this app will have poor eyesight.

Is there any simple way to change the font-size with jquery-mobile?

When I try to add entries in a custom css file, there are unexpected results (Formatting goes out, etc) I have also tried theme-roller, but that only allows you to change the font-family, not the font-size.

eg:

```
body p {
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Even just a general explanation about how to write a css file for jquery-mobile would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've worked it out.

In the jquery-mobile-1.2.0.css file is the styling for query-mobile. You modify this stuff.

There's some cryptic info on the jquery-mobile website that will make sense once you've read this.

So, to change the font-size for

within all

you go to the jquery-mobile-1.2.0.css file and add:

```
.ui-li p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

It seams that most of the jquery-mobile elements have .ui- in from of their normal html tags. They have a special class or something. (If anyone wants to elaborate on this it'd be great.)

Comment: "here's some cryptic info on the jquery-mobile website" where? I cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting global `<body>`'s `font-size` should be enough:

```
body {
  font-size: 15px; // You can even use !important 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem. It is only applied to some text. But if you've got text in a list view, it's still tiny. If you attach an !important after the font-size line it causes mayhem with the formatting of listviews.